# Existing Entity in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I know that there has been a lot of discussion about determining if a Core Data Entity is unique or not, but I am having a lot of trouble understanding the various solutions that people have thrown out.  Hopefully, someone can provide me a simple solution.

Situation:

I have an entity that is basically a many-to-many relationship (Event -> Attendee <- People).  The people are references to Address Book entries (I am storing the AddressBookID, firstName, lastName and a createdOn date in the People entity).  In the Event table, I have details about  the event.  In the Attendee table, I have a relationship to the Event (event) and the People (person) and a createdOn date for sorting purposes.

Problem:
I want to check whether the user has already added the Person to the Event before I insert a Attendee record.

In a traditional database, I'd create a Unique Key constraint.  When I attempt to insert the duplicate, it would throw an error, I'd trap it and move on (likely update the existing record with the latest data).

I've tried the following:

```
#pragma mark - Selected People Delegate
-(void)returnPeople:(NSMutableArray *)selectedPeople
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    Attendee *newAttendee; 

    for (Attendee *selectedPerson in selectedPeople) {

        if (self.context == nil) {
            NSLog(@"NSManagedObjectContext is nil");
//            return nil;
        }


         newAttendee = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Attendee" inManagedObjectContext:context];


        [event addAttendeeObject:newAttendee];

        newAttendee.createdOn = [NSDate date];

        newAttendee.event = event;
        newAttendee.person = selectedPerson;


        NSLog(@"Person ID: %@", [selectedPerson.objectID description] );

        if ([self uniqueEntityExistsWithEnityName:@"Attendee" UniqueKey:@"person" UniqueValue:[selectedPerson.objectID description] SortAttribute:@"createdOn" ManagedObjectContext:context]) {
            NSLog(@"Attendee Exists!");
        }

        if (![context save:&error]) {
            // Handle the error.
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

        error = nil;
        self.eventAttendee = nil;

        [self.attendees insertObject:newAttendee atIndex:0];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

        [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"Event Attendee Added"];


    }


}

#pragma mark - Core Data - Manage Attendees

-(BOOL)uniqueEntityExistsWithEnityName:(NSString*)entityName UniqueKey:(NSString*) uniqueKey UniqueValue:(NSString*)uniqueValue SortAttribute:(NSString*)sortDescriptorAttribute ManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*) context1;
{
    BOOL returnValue = NO;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    //what is the correct predates to compare the text an string core data property against a passed in string?
    //    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"unique= %@", uniqueValue];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@=%@", uniqueKey, uniqueValue];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:sortDescriptorAttribute ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];   

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [context1 executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!matches)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: no object matches");
    }
    else if([matches count] > 1) {
        NSLog(@"Error: More than one object for unique record");
        returnValue = YES;

    } else if ([matches count] == 0) {
        returnValue = NO;
    } else {
        returnValue = YES;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Jason

Comment: What is your issue in the code?

Comment: The issue with my code is that with the uniqueEntityExistsWithEnityName method, it never finds that I have already added a person.  So, it is basically returning FALSE when it should return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
After comments.

OK, your problem is not adding a Person to Event.  Your problem is adding a an Attendee to an Event, where that Attendee has a certain relationship.

In that case, I would first do a simple fetch similar to...

```
// Find all Attendee objects that are linked to both our event and person
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Attendee"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(event.name = %@) AND (person.name = %@)", eventName, personName];
```

Then, you can do your fetch.  You will get back all Attendee objects that contain both the event you are looking for, and the specified person.  Now, if you get nothing back, that person has not been added as an attendee.

If you will have lots of objects, there are other ways to do this that will be faster (depending on the attributes that have indexes and other factors).  Using joins (i.e., relationships in predicates) is not super fast, and unless you specify index attributes all searching is linear.

Comment: Hi Jody, thank you very much for taking the time to provide some insight on my issue.  I appreciate it!  Regarding your response, I do have To-Many Relationship checked, but it is still allowing me to add the same person to the same event multiple titles (basically creating unique key constraint violation).  Within my table view, I am seeing the same person added multiple times.

Comment: NOTE: I have implemented the following solution as a workaround: I create an NSArray with all the Attendee(s) for the selected Event.  Then, I loop through the array and check the objectID description for each Person against the Person that is attempting to be added.  If I find it, I return YES, otherwise NO.  This is working, but it seems really inefficient (i.e., what if I had a lot of Attendee(s) - in my cases it will only be a few for each Event.)  Any way, I will leave this open for another day or two, and then I will update the case with code.

Comment: Hi Jody, after reading through your post another time, I realized that my original question may not have clearly laid out that I have 3 tables (entities) = Event, Attendee & Person.  Attendee has to Relationships (event & person).  To determine if I have a duplicate, I think that I need to check the objectID of both the Event and Person.

Comment: Hi Jody, thanks for updating with more details!!!  Quick question, I am only storing the relationships and a createdOn date.  Basically, the Attendee has the following properties Attendee.event, Attendee.person & Attendee.createdOn.  person and event are relationships.  So, question, how would you use the predicate with objectIDs instead?